# Org file with tag system like gmail, with item under multiple headers synchronised

Tags: org-mode

How do I get Org-mode do this, similar to gmail's tags.

`** Header 1
*** Under header 1
*** Under header 1 and 2
    This content is synchronised
** Header 2
*** Under header 1 and 2
    This content is synchronised`

If I edit anything under `Under header 1 and 2`, then every instance of it should be changed, no matter where I edit it.

Usage case:  Large categorised list of items that sometimes fall under multiple categories.  Need to be able to find the item in any of its categories.

Comment: The flat text file is just that.  Do you really want more than one of the same entry floating around in your master file?  Wouldn't you prefer that the master file not have duplicates, and you can invest your time configuring a custom `*Org Agenda*` buffer?

Comment: I want to have the same item appear under several headings, and I want all instances of it to update/synchronise.  It's important to the use case because the org file will be shared and different people will look for the items under different headings.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the fact that you are not interested in using an `*Org Agenda*` buffer and that you wish to modify the flat text master org-mode file.  I do not believe there is a sufficient built-in infrastructure to handle your new feature request, and implementing it may be too large a task to be considered answerable within the context of this forum.  But, perhaps someone will be motivated enough to write something up . . .